# Can I use month variables to capture linear increases and seasonal effects in the same model?

Tags: r, time-series, generalized-additive-model, count-data

I have count data (numbers of articles published) that I want to model as a function of time and location. I suspect there's an increasing linear effect with time but also a seasonal boost in the summer. Further, I think the pattern may differ depending on the location.

My data are daily but I've summed the counts by country to monthly, otherwise I get a lot of zeroes.

In a GAM framework, can I use month both to capture the seasonal effects and the linear increase? In the latter case, because I have multiple years, I felt like this would be ok to do because I can stop nmonth resetting to 1 when the year runs over.

My data look like this:

```
count month nmonth country
2     Jan     1     1
3     Feb     2     1
4     Mar     3     1
1     Apr     4     1
2     May     5     1
3     Jun     6     1
4     Jul     7     1
5     Aug     8     1
6     Sep     9     1
7     Oct     10    1
1     Nov     11    1
1     Dec     12    1
1     Jan     13    1
2     Jan     1     2
3     Feb     2     2
4     Mar     3     2
1     Apr     4     2
1     May     5     2
7     Jun     6     2
3     Jul     7     2
2     Aug     8     2
6     Sep     9     2
7     Oct     10    2
8     Nov     11    2
2     Dec     12    2
9     Jan     13    2
```

Thus, my model would be:

```
gam(count ~ s(month, country) + s(nmonth, country), family = poisson...)
```

Comment: Including two interactions with country in the same model will exhaust the degrees of freedom. First, try estimating the country, categorical month and linear trend fields separately to establish their independent effects. Next, include two main effects at a time (3 models). Finally, include all three as main effects, building up to the full model.

Comment: Your pseudo code doesn't make sense; how are you smoothing a factor?

Comment: In your example data you don't have a year variable and the data only extend beyond 1 year by 1 month. How many countries and how many years do you have?

Comment: I have approx 20 years of data across 5 countries (UK and Ireland).  The smooth should be an interaction of the continuous variable (e.g.) month with the factor variable (country). You answered a related question here for me Gavin [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77487084/how-can-i-create-a-gam-that-has-two-date-scales-that-interact-with-a-factor). How to deal with counts that can sum up is why I'm investigating how best to approach this.